# Integrating iAd into UITableView iOS app

Tags: uitableview, ios7, iad

I have a UITableView with data in the cells.  When I run it on it's own everything works.  When I integrate the iAD, the iAD shows up, but then my cells are not showing up anymore in the UITableView.  It's almost as if the IAD overrides the view, which is odd to me, since in my storyboard, I placed the iAD just on the bottom of the table view.  Not sure what's going on here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out on my own.  For anyone having the same issue hope this helps.  So seems like in this case, when integrating the iAD into the UITableView, you will need to implement the viewWillShow method inside your Table View Controller implementation file like so:

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
     [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
```

Once I did this, everything worked perfectly.

Edited: Another little bit of information I learned while trying to figure this out.  The viewDidLoad method is only called once during execution.  Use the viewWillAppear method if you want something to execute again after initial load.  This method is called anything a view is accessed.